# How to make a custom embed based on input gathered from user input through a prompt - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a suggestions command, where if the user types `=suggest` in the server, it would create a prompt in their DM's, asking for different specifications.

However, I am unsure how to obtain user input and use that input in an embed. How would I do this?

**For example:**
The bot would ask in DM's *"What would you like the title to be?"*, and then the user would respond with their desired title, and it would set that input as the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a message collector. I used [`channel.awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) here:

```js
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'suggest') {
    // send the question
    message.channel.send('What would you like the title to be?');

    // use a filter to only collect a response from the message author
    const filter = (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id;
    // only accept a maximum of one message, and error after one minute
    const options = { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] };

    message.channel
      .awaitMessages(filter, options)
      .then((collected) => {
        // the first collected message's content will be the title
        const title = collected.first().content;
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(title)
          .setDescription('This embed has a custom title');

        message.channel.send(embed);
      })
      .catch((collected) =>
        console.log(`After a minute, only collected ${collected.size} messages.`),
      );
  }
});
```

[image]

I've just noticed that you wanted to send it in a DM. In that case, you can [`.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User?scrollTo=send) the first message, wait for it to be resolved, so you can add a message collector in the channel using [`channel.createMessageCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector). I've added some comments to explain it:

```js
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const MINUTES = 5;

  if (command === 'suggest') {
    const questions = [
      { answer: null, field: 'title' },
      { answer: null, field: 'description' },
      { answer: null, field: 'author name' },
      { answer: null, field: 'colour' },
    ];
    let current = 0;

    // wait for the message to be sent and grab the returned message
    // so we can add the message collector
    const sent = await message.author.send(
      `**Question 1 of ${questions.length}:**\nWhat would you like the ${questions[current].field} be?`,
    );

    const filter = (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id;
    // send in the DM channel where the original question was sent
    const collector = sent.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      max: questions.length,
      time: MINUTES * 60 * 1000,
    });

    // fires every time a message is collected
    collector.on('collect', (message) => {
      // add the answer and increase the current index
      questions[current++].answer = message.content;
      const hasMoreQuestions = current < questions.length;

      if (hasMoreQuestions) {
        message.author.send(
          `**Question ${current + 1} of ${questions.length}:**\nWhat would you like the ${questions[current].field} be?`,
        );
      }
    });

    // fires when either times out or when reached the limit
    collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'time') {
        return message.author.send(
          `I'm not saying you're slow but you only answered ${collected.size} questions out of ${questions.length} in ${MINUTES} minutes. I gave up.`,
        );
      }

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(questions[0].answer)
        .setDescription(questions[1].answer)
        .setAuthor(questions[2].answer)
        .setColor(questions[3].answer);

      message.author.send('Here is your embed:');
      message.author.send(embed);
      // send a message for confirmation
      message.author.send('Would you like it to be published? `y[es]/n[o]`');
      message.author.dmChannel
        .awaitMessages(
          // set up a filter to only accept y, yes, n, and no
          (m) => ['y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'].includes(m.content.toLowerCase()),
          { max: 1 },
        )
        .then((coll) => {
          let response = coll.first().content.toLowerCase();
          if (['y', 'yes'].includes(response)) {
            // publish embed, like send in a channel, etc
            // then let the member know that you've finished
            message.author.send('Great, the embed is published.');
          } else {
            // nothing else to do really, just let them know what happened
            message.author.send('Publishing the embed is cancelled.');
          }
        })
        .catch((coll) => console.log('handle error'));
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

PS: You can learn more about message collectors on [DiscordJS.guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors).

Comment: Hey! Amazing code, it works fantastic. How would I make it send the final embed in DM's AND THEN prompt the user with a "YES/NO" prompt?