# How to collect user input and add that to my choice of template and verify before sending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to work on a project where I can get collector to collect user input and load it to my template and shows me to verify it before sending.

Format is :
[This if template format I want currently trying to collect user input for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRDMZ.png)

Comment: Your question is too broad. However, this answer does exactly what you're looking for: [How to make a custom embed based on input gathered from user input through a prompt - Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822635/how-to-make-a-custom-embed-based-on-input-gathered-from-user-input-through-a-pro) Try to change it to your own needs and if there is anything wrong with it, create a new post with the details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write all your code for you, but I can definitely point you in the right direction! What you're probably looking for is the [string split function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). This lets you take an input string and turn it into an array. For example, the string `hello, this is a test, I think?` could be split on the `,` character, and the result would be `["hello", "this is a test", "I think?"]`. In your case, this can be used to take the user's message, and split it into the template parts you need. Then you can just iterate through the resulting array and add each part to the correct spot in the template!

As for verifying the message before sending, there's a ton of ways that can be accomplished. One way just off the top of my head is that you can send the message to a private verification channel, then use a [reaction collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector) to verify or deny it. If it's verified, you can set the bot to send the message wherever.

I would recommend reading over [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/). That site has an incredibly large amount of useful information/code that will be able to help you with pretty much anything you could need!