# making an embed creator command using a prefix discord bot instead of slash commands? node.js

Tags: discord.js, bots

im a noob when it comes to discord bot developing, and ive been looking everywhere for the ability to make a custom embed creator command, where you send the command and it gives you prompts to make a custom embed, instead of having to code individual embeds in vscode.

every tutorial ive seen has been with using slash commands, but my bot uses its own custom prefix and i dont want to go through the hassle of making slash command builders and the lot.

any help on a way to make a custom embed creator command using the bots own prefix would be very much appreciated :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a custom embed based on input gathered from user input through a prompt - Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822635/how-to-make-a-custom-embed-based-on-input-gathered-from-user-input-through-a-pro)

Comment: it does! however i dont want it to be prompted through dms and im not sure how im supposed to alter the code to make it reply to messages into the channel that the command was made in

Comment: actually, im running into quite a few problems :/

Comment: Sounds like you should practice JS and learn more about the library you are using first.

Comment: sounds like there was no need for that comment